# RavenDB always return no facets

Tags: c#, ravendb, facet, faceted-search

I'm trying to get a facets from RavenDB 3.0. 
My code looks like:

```
        using (var session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            var result = session.Query<ProductSearchDocument>(indexName);
            var facetQuery = result.ToFacets(facetDocName);
        }
```

But all facets values are 0. So I get all facets from facet document but for each of it hit is always 0.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe your index has stale results?
Take a look on this piece of code:
https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/v3.0/Raven.Tests.Core/Querying/Searching.cs#L318
Index definition: https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/v3.0/Raven.Tests.Core/Utils/Indexes/CameraCost.cs